# Generate a binary values dictionary by searching in two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists

```
list1=['ABC','DBA','CBA','RBA','DCA','RMA']
list2=['ABC,'DBA','RMA']
```

Expected Output

```
{'ABC':1,'DBA':1,'CBA':0,'RBA':0,'DCA':0,'RMA':1}
```

if the values of list1 are present in list2 then the values of output dictionary would be 1, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of `list2` is small, you can use a simple dictionary comprehension:

```py
{key: int(key in list2) for key in list1}
```

However, if `list2` is long, you should turn it into a set for faster lookups:

```py
lookup_set = set(list2)
{key: int(key in lookup_set) for key in list1}
```

Both of these output:

```py
{'ABC': 1, 'DBA': 1, 'CBA': 0, 'RBA': 0, 'DCA': 0, 'RMA': 1}
```

Comment: Note that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `True=1` and `False=0` so you could store `True` and `False` in the dictionary and it would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=['ABC','DBA','CBA','RBA','DCA','RMA']
list2=['ABC','DBA','RMA']

output = {}
for x in list1:
    output[x] = 0

for x in list2:
    if (x in output):
        output[x] = 1
    else:
        output[x] = 0

print(output) # {'ABC': 1, 'DBA': 1, 'CBA': 0, 'RBA': 0, 'DCA': 0, 'RMA': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

If list1 will always contain all possible keys

`{s:int(s in list2) for s in list1}`

But in the general case, where there could be distinct keys in either, this will work

`{s:int(s in list2 and s in list1) for s in list1+list2}`

Note: Because python can automatically interpret booleans as integers then the only reason to cast to int is if you need to print the dictionary. Otherwise I would just leave the values as True/False